# Flutter - Firebase Autologin and Email Authentication Error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a login code through firebase. I want to log in only to the user who signed up and certified by email and set it up so that it can be automatically logged in. Created code with streambuilder for automatic login. However, the automatic login email authentication error occurs when the receiver is null. Is there a way to put the receiver in? Or I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutteridmemo/pages/log_in_page.dart';
import 'package:flutteridmemo/pages/memo_page.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Directory document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(document.path);
  await Hive.openBox<String>("DB");
  runApp(MyApp());
}

bool isFirstData = true;

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FirebaseUser _firebaseUser;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      title: 'ID_Memo_Memo',
      home: StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (isFirstData) {
            isFirstData = false;
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasData && _firebaseUser.isEmailVerified == true) {
              return MemoPage();
            } else {
              return LogInPage();
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error.

```
I/flutter (14699): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building             
StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (14699): _StreamBuilderBaseState<FirebaseUser,         
AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser>>#963d7):
I/flutter (14699): The getter 'isEmailVerified' was called on null.
I/flutter (14699): Receiver: null
I/flutter (14699): Tried calling: isEmailVerified
I/flutter (14699): 
I/flutter (14699): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (14699):   StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser> enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'isEmailVerified'` was called on null, means `_firebaseUser` is null. You didnt initialize `_firebaseUser`, since you are using `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` inside a `StreamBuilder`, it should return `Stream<FirebaseUser>`, therefore you should use the variable `snapshot` which is of type `AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser>` to check if the email is verified or not.

```
 else {
            if (snapshot.hasData &&snapshot.data.isEmailVerified == true) {
              return MemoPage();
            } else {
              return LogInPage();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks to you, the problem was solved. Thank you for giving me a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

So this is happening, even if snapshot doesn't contain the data, i.e. even if it is null, you are trying to call isEmailVerified on it. Change your code to something similar like this:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  if(_firebaseUser.isEmailVerified == true){
    return MemoPage();
  }
}else{
    return LogInPage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me the solution. It's a good solution, but I chose a different method because I thought the other method was better. However, I learned various methods by teaching me how to do this way . Thank you.